# Remove special character from SQL field

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, unicode, special-characters

One of the columns in my select statement has the line tabulation character i.e., &#xb. I am using this field in a xml file and when i get an error illegal character in XML file. Is there a way in sql to avoid/replace special characters.

I have been looking at this link

https://www.sqlshack.com/replace-ascii-special-characters-sql-server/

but just wondering if there is a easier way of doing this.

I have tried this with no luck

```
declare @test nvarchar(50) = 'abe&#xbprakash'
select ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test, '!', ''), '#', ''), '$', ''), '&', ''), '') AS [Address1]
set @test = 'Peacehaven ChildrenÍs CentreMeridian Way
'
select ISNULL(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@test, '!', ''), '#', ''), '$', ''), '&', ''), '') AS [Address2]
```

Result:
[image: Result]

The text with special character is as follows
'Peacehaven ChildrenÍs CentreMeridian Way'

Comment: Is replace function not working for your requirement.

Comment: `REPLACE` in some fashion is going to be what you want for this...so no, not really an *easier* way unless you do it on the front end with `REGEX`

Comment: There are no special characters **in Unicode**. The web page you see uses Unicode stored in SQL Servcer `nvarchar` fields, which is why I can type `αυτό εδώ` and be certain it will be displayed correctly.

Comment: Please post your code and the table schema. SQL Server **won't** complain about *any* character stored in an nvarchar field. It will complain only about invalid characters stored in `xml`-typed fields. You'll get into problems though, if you try to construct a query using string concatenation, or if a client application stores invalid XML and then tries to parse it back

Comment: From Wikipedia's article on [Tab Characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) : `The vertical tab is &#xB; but is not allowed in SGML; this includes XML 1.0 and HTML.`. You shouldn't have this sequence in an XML file in the first place. This shouldn't be stored anywhere people or code expect XML content

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Thank you. The xml file uses what is returned from sql so I am planning on using the SQL Replace function to look for special characters.

Comment: @Abe only if someone *put it there* by storing a plain text string into a `varchar` or `nvarchar` field. An `xml` field would have complained. Where did that sequence come from? How was this data generated? That's what needs fixing.

Comment: @Abe if you don't use the `xml` type you should ensure that the data stored in the database is correct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The field is basically a address field which goes into XML element called address. I have tried sql replace and updated my question. Still no luck though.

Comment: @Abe you haven't provided any information yet. No query, no table script, no test data. Did you try to replace the vertical tab character or the 4-character sequence `&#xb`? Does the field contain vertical tabs or the four-letter sequence? Did someone try to store multiple address lines using the vertical tab as a separator, instead of newline? Or worse, multiple *addresses* that may contain newlines?

Comment: @Abe if the text contains vertical tabs, you can replace them with `REPLACE(field,CHAR(11),' ')` or `REPLACE(field,NCHAR(11),' ')`. If it contains the four-letter sequence, `REPLACE(field,'&#xb',' ')`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - i am going to use the Replace and hardcode the characters '&#xb' and include all other checks as well. Thank you.

Comment: @Abe that meanst there are no vertical tabs in your text but a four-letter sequence

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question and all the comments gives me the feeling, that you have sort of a misconception about *special characters*.

First of all, you must know, that SQL-Server knows two kinds of string:

- VARCHAR (which is 1-byte-encoded *extended ASCII* with a very small character support
- NVARCHAR (which is 2-byte-encoded *UCS-2*, which is almost the same as `UTF-16`. You can say this is *unicode*, therefore supporting almost any existing character).

Very important to know: A literal is - by default of type `VARCHAR`. Setting such a literal to a variable declared as `NVARCHAR` will still handle the literal as `VARCHAR`. To deal with a literal as `NVARCHAR` needs a leading `N`.

Try this

```
SELECT  'Кто там?' AS RussianWithoutTheN    --??? ????
      ,N'Кто там?' AS TheSameWithTheN       --Кто там?
```

So your code

```
declare @test nvarchar(50) = 'abe&#xbprakash'
set @test = 'Peacehaven ChildrenÍs CentreMeridian Way
'
```

... would need the `N` to persist any hidden character...

Now about XML:

XML is `NVARCHAR` under the hood, no need for worrying about such characters:

Try this:

```
SELECT  'Кто там?' AS RussianWithoutTheN 
      ,N'Кто там?' AS TheSameWithTheN
FOR XML PATH('Test')
```

The result

```
<Test>
  <RussianWithoutTheN>??? ????</RussianWithoutTheN>
  <TheSameWithTheN>Кто там?</TheSameWithTheN>
</Test>
```

But there are some **forbidden** characters. XML is a text-based container. This means:

- There are some unprintable characters
- There are some characters forming the markup (especially `<, > and &`

Try this:

```
SELECT  'Some <forbidden> text' AS ReplacedEntities 
FOR XML PATH('Test')
```

The result:

```
<Test>
  <ReplacedEntities>Some &lt;forbidden&gt; text</ReplacedEntities>
</Test>
```

The engine had to replace the brackets with the corresponding entities.

**Important 1**: You should never try to do this yourself. This is done by the XML-engine implicitly.

**Important 2**: Reading the XML will automatically re-replace the entities. Never try to do this your self...

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Test>
  <ReplacedEntities>Some &lt;forbidden&gt; text</ReplacedEntities>
</Test>';

SELECT @xml.value('(/Test/ReplacedEntities/text())[1]','nvarchar(100)') 

returns "Some <forbidden> text"
```

You see, that the engine will do all the hard work for you...

About your real issue: You did not provide the string making troubles (please avoid pictures!). But you can replace a NVARCHAR-character using a N-literal or the function `NCHAR()` to get the correct value. Otherwise you are dealing just with *question marks* (see example at the beginning).

Hope this helps...